Changing line height in CSS makes editing not work
I tried this solution for reducing the spacing between rows of text when using auto height and wrap text. This is the only css customization I currently have, otherwise I am using ag-grid.css and ag-theme-quartz.css.
This simple change causes any edits in table cells to silently fail. Any ideas what could be going wrong? I have no idea why changing the line height of auto height cells would do this.
Thanks
